# Is there a way to generate build-info.json locally while doing mvn deploy?

Tags: java, maven, artifactory

I am using this plugin https://github.com/jfrog/build-info to publish build info to Artifactory

I want to access the build-info.json in a folder for ex: /target folder when I run `mvn deploy` Is there a way to do that?

We have an internal observability tool that uses the build-info. We moved from Jenkins to AWS Codebuild. Jenkins had a plugin which provided this file, now I am trying to generate it *manually*

Comment: Still, I think I miss something - Why do you need this file locally? Would you consider downloading it from Artifactory?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory) to get the build info data.

Run the following jf commands:

1. `jf mvn deploy --build-name=mybuild --build-number=1`
2. `jf rt bp mybuild 1 --dry-run > build-info.json`

Comment: Also https://github.com/jfrog/build-info-go, but without knowing his use-case it is hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description, I believe [Artifactory Maven Plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Maven+Artifactory+Plugin) should be helpful where you can capture the build info and push to the Artifactory, therefore, having a build-info.json for each build you do.

Comment: I am using that plugin, but I don't see a build-info.json file on my local machine